# Solutions of of $x^{76}=1$ in $U_{77}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

"Let $s$ be the number of solutions in $U_{77}$ of the equation $x^{76}=1.$ Without explicitly finding all solutions of the equation, explain why $s$ must divide $60$."

I do not understand the correlation between $U_{77}$ and why $s$ must divide $60$.

Comment: It seems that the crux of the problem is to find the correlation. Can you somehow relate $60$ to the group $U_{77}$? You must have given some thought to where $60$ comes from -- if you share you ideas about this in your post, then other users will be able to offer more appropriate answers.

Comment: 76 is not significant

Answer (score 2):

Let $S\subset U_{77}$ the set of solutions in $U_{77}$ of the equation $x^{76}=1$ so $|S|=s$.

Also $|U_{77}|=\phi(77)=60$.

Show that $S$ is a subgroup of $U_{77}$ and by Lagrange theorem $|S|=s|60=|U_{77}|$.

Comment: how do i show that S is a subgroup of U_77?

Comment: @user167668 - By definition. For example it is not empty because $1\in S$

Comment: Just go through and verify the group axioms.  If $x^{76} = 1$ and $y^{76} = 1$, then does $xy^{76} = 1$?  If $x^{76} = 1$, then what about $x^{-1}$?  Consider these to show closure under multiplication and existence of inverses.

Comment: Of course I meant to write $(xy)^{76}$, but MSE won't let me edit my comment.

Comment: with x and y are there specific numbers that go there or many different combinations or are they both the same number? I dont really understand the group axioms aspect.

Comment: Well, $U_{77}$ is a group.  If we let $S$ be the set of elements in $U_{77}$ that satisfy $x^{76} = 1$, then we wish to show that $S$ is a group (a subgroup of $U_{77}$).  To show that as in above, we let $x$ and $y$ be any arbitrary elements in $S$.  They could be the same, or they could be different.  If $x \in S$ and $y \in S$, we need to show that $xy \in S$.  Further, if $x \in S$, then we need to show that $x^{-1} \in S$.  That is the motivation in my comment above.

Comment: @GastónBurrull,    Why not $|U_{77}|=\lambda(77)=30?$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I mean the order of a group not the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: What is the order of $U_{77}$ ?

Comment: Useful short hint. :)